# What is the difference between 000-default.conf and just default

Tags: virtualhost

I am following a guide to getting vhosts working with Apache2 and most guide are talking about 000-default.conf but I only have "default" in /etc/apache2/sites-available/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is dependent on your OS. I suppose you are on a different OS (or even version) then the tutorial you are referring to.

In most distributions the default apache configuration will load any file which name ends in .conf in this directory or even any file in the directory. So as long as it gets included from the main apache configuration file your good.

The `000-` is kind of a trick to get the file load first as they are alphabetically sorted.

Answer (score 0):

The number prefixes are used for symlinks in the `sites-enabled` directory in order to define a priority for the vhosts. For the actual files in `sites-available` there is no need for such number prefixes.

In general there is very little limitations to how you can name the files in `sites-available`, but for `sites-enabled` you should keep using whatever naming convention your distribution was using originally.

Notice that some versions require names in `sites-enabled` to end with `.conf`.